# Root DNS servers report wrong NS

Tags: domain-name-system, root

I have an issue with the last step of DNS delegation by the root servers.

I have transferred a domain from registrar A to registrar B a couple of months back and forgot about it, until I had to change the DNS records to reflect our new server location and noticed that nothing updated until I changed it in the panel of our old provider.

This is what it currently looks like:

Panel of OLD PROVIDER:

```
euro-business.de. IN SOA ns1.antagus.de
euro-business.de. IN NS ns1.antagus.de
euro-business.de. IN NS ns2.antagus.de
euro-business.de. IN A 78.46.57.101
euro-business.de. IN MX mx.examplemx.com
```

Panel of NEW PROVIDER:

```
euro-business.de. IN SOA ns1.antagus.de
euro-business.de. IN NS ns1.antagus.de
euro-business.de. IN NS ns2.antagus.de
euro-business.de. IN A 82.98.201.230
euro-business.de. IN MX 10 mx.examplemx.com
```

When I do a DNS delegation check and query root DNS servers, I get `78.46.57.101` as a result, which is the old and thus incorrect A record. All DNS root servers report `ns1.fastdns.de` as the authoritative DNS server, which is wrong!

If I query `ns1.antagus.de` using dig, I get the correct results. The root servers however point to the incorrect NS and A records.

I've tried everything I know, including updating the records and on the old and new panel, but it doesn't seem to get to the root servers. I'd appreciate some help. If you need the domain in question, it's euro-business.de and it should point to ns1.antagus.de and ns2.antagus.de for the name servers.

Comment: I get `ns1.antagus.de` and `ns2.antagus.de` as the nameservers, and an IP of 78.46.57.101 for the root domain. Given you've censored the IPs, it's hard to know if that's the right value or not.

Comment: That is the incorrect IP. I will update my post to show the actual IPs.

Comment: If the correct nameservers are returning the incorrect IP, contact that provider for assistance.

Comment: I have done that, the reply was something like "Update the records in the customer panel" - which I've done numerous times. I'm currently waiting on another reply to a follow-up E-Mail I've sent. The issue is DNS root servers returning ns1.fastdns.de when they should be returning ns1.antagus.de.

Comment: @ephidrineon I'm not sure which "DNS root servers" you're referring to, but https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/euro-business.de indicates your NS records are resolving to `ns1/ns2.antagus.de` as you expect, globally.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that link. I have a feeling I know the answer to my problem, I have to wait for propagation though to confirm that. I will let everyone know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When troubleshooting DNS issues, ask the authoritative nameserver first.

Here you should start at the registry.

This gives you which nameservers are authoritative at the registry (.DE):

```
$ dig NS de. +short
s.de.net.
f.nic.de.
z.nic.de.
n.de.net.
a.nic.de.
l.de.net.
```

(this was a shortcut, in theory you would have to ask the root servers to know the list of .DE nameservers, here I am just using my local recursive nameserver and trusting it).

Now you can contact any of this nameserver (they should all reply the same thing for the same query) and ask it about your domain name. You are interested only in the "AUTHORITY SECTION" so here it goes:

```
$ dig @z.nic.de euro-business.de. NS

[..]

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
euro-business.de.   1d IN NS ns2.antagus.de.
euro-business.de.   1d IN NS ns1.antagus.de.
```

Those are the nameservers you need to query about your domain name.

And they say:

```
$ dig @ns2.antagus.de. euro-business.de. A +short
82.98.201.230
```

At the end of the day, it seems you changed your authoritative nameservers at some point from

```
ns1.fastdns.de
ns2.fastdns.de
ns3.fastdns.de
```

to

```
ns1.antagus.de
ns2.antagus.de
```

And each set of nameservers was not serving the exact same information.

So while there is technically no propagation, but still time to wait, you may not have waited enough (or could have avoided the problem altogether by first changing the IP address in the old nameservers then, after waiting some time again, changing nameservers).

Why some time? Because it depends on the TTL but:

- authoritative nameservers decide the TTL but then each recursive nameserver will get its value, depending on if you used it or not to query; said differently: depending on which recursive nameserver you query you may get different results, which also has the direct consequences that when troubleshooting you should always start by querying authoritative nameservers
- and, by the way, there is also another TTL for negative replies
- note that in theory recursive nameservers are free to ditch values before the TTL is reached (it is only a maximum value), but in practice they will also rewrite some insanely small TTLs, like everything under 5 minutes (empirically) may be treated as 5 minutes and not something else (so forget about TTLs of like 5 seconds). They are in theory wrong to do that, but in practice probably right. And anyway it exists.

PS: "I have an issue with the last step of DNS delegation by the root servers." This is surely not the case. At most you could say something about .DE TLD servers, but there is nothing about your problem that is related to root servers, the one dealing with the `.` zone that hosts only nameservers for TLDs.
Note also that typically registrar changes have no consequences on the DNS side of things (because the registrar is changed without any change to the nameservers) except of course if you used your previous registrar also as a DNS provider, but this is certainly not mandatory.

Answer (score 4):

Your nameservers are set incorrectly at your domain registrar.

The whois record reports:

```
Domain: euro-business.de
Nserver: ns1.fastdns.de
Nserver: ns2.fastdns.de
Nserver: ns3.fastdns.de
```

DENIC does not tell the public who your domain registrar is. You need to contact the registrar and set the nameservers to the ones you intended to use. This is done separately from setting DNS records. You probably also should verify that DENIC has the correct registrar, as they show your domain's record was last updated in 2009. [They will provide this information to you when you prove you are the domain holder.](https://www.denic.de/webwhois-web20/en) It's possible that your domain wasn't actually transferred correctly.

Comment: Valuable information. I will let the previous registrar know to update the records.

Comment: What appears in whois has no operational consequences and hence to troubleshoot DNS issues, DNS queries are better than looking at whois.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Really? How, then, does the registrar's selection of nameservers get from the registrar to the root nameservers?

Comment: Yes, really. Whois is just output from the registry database, it has 0 operational consequences. You can remove whois altogether right now: domains will continue to work. "How, then, does the registrar's selection of nameservers get from the registrar to the root nameservers?" The registrar is connected by EPP (typically) to the registry and all provisioning goes through that canal. EPP is XML over TLS and obviously not open to the public. There is nothing about "root nameservers" (for the `.` zone) that is relevant here. Registrar is just a middleman passing information to the registry.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek OK, I think I see what you're saying, but I don't see how it's relevant. His problem is precisely that the wrong nameservers are being used on the global Internet. This is something that you fix at your registrar, and then they use EPP (typically) etc. to make the changes live. That appears to not have happened in this user's case. Worse, it might be that his domain transfer didn't even happen.

Comment: Yes but it still remains that to troubleshoot DNS issues you have better to use DNS queries than whois. Whois ("soon" to be replaced by RDAP) is useful in only one very specific case: to discover if the domain is on "serverHold"/"clientHold" which would make it disappear from registry nameservers. Besides that for all other cases it is better to use the DNS, that was the major point I wanted to convey and I expanded in my own reply. Depending on whois seems to me giving a bad direction (whois is not necessarily updated in real time, people do not use registry whois but others, etc.)

Comment: "Worse, it might be that his domain transfer didn't even happen. " The domain transfer is orthogonal to a change of DNS provider and consequences of it if both are not using the same zone content. Obviously, problems are tied if one of the registrar is also one of the DNS provider. People often confuse registrars with DNS providers (or web/email providerS) and confuse change of registrars, change of nameservers, change of content of zone served by some nameservers. I think it is important to clearly separate all these points.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek It looks like this user managed to fix their problem over the last few hours. Both whois and DNS now report their intended nameservers. So it appears we're trying to diagnose a solved problem anyway.

Comment: "So it appears you're trying to diagnose a solved problem anyway. " I am not trying to diagnose this specific problem per se, but giving enough details for people to be able to reproduce the methodology later for any similar problem. I think it is more important to give blueprints and tools to solve all problems than specific solutions to only a given one. My answer could be useful for troubleshooting many other DNS issues as it conveys an important message often forgotten: use the DNS to troubleshoot the DNS, start at root and with authoritative nameservers, query recursive ones later.